# How do I change the wordpress twenty twelve header php admin options to include an upload logo section?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, admin, graphical-logo

Hi helpful wordpressers

I would like to make the wordpress twenty twelve theme more accessible. 
I want to be able to replace the logo without having to dip into the code, CSS or FTP each time.

I know twenty eleven sort of had this option in place because the header image could be used instead however this was also bad as it hid the seo heading.

Basically I would like to overlay the logo on the seo heading with CSS tricks.

I guess this involves some php editing. Being a designer/front end developer I am not as familiar with this.

Thanks for all your help

Judi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow Thanks very much found the answer here

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-move-menu-below-header-image-in-twenty-twelve-theme?replies=39

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using the custom header to upload a new image? (Appearance > Header)
http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-header 
If you want the image to be SEO friendly you can go to MEDIA and and add a title to the Alternate Text  of the image.

Comment: Sorry thats not seo friendly it must be a h1 tag!